# I can't find other pratners tab when I open ubuntu software center?

Tags: software-sources

When I open the Software Centre there is no tab for other software partners. I am trying to install a third-party repository and can't find the page or edit button. I have tried clicking on every tab that I can find, I even tried the search box and got the "can not find as an answer" message. How do I find this page?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it in software updater  , under other software tab.

[image]